# Can one chinese character represent many different words?

Tags: simplified-characters

Take a look at this character

https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=0&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E5%87%A0

几

It has 3 meanings and has a different tone

[image]

If it's true that one character can represent other words, please show me other samples.

Comment: Haven't you just answered your own question?

Comment: I don't believe it's true. There must be something wrong. If so please show me other samples

Comment: This phenomenon is very common in Chinese.  Pick a random character from a Chinese dictionary, and there's a decent chance of it having multiple meanings.  Just like how *set* has [dozens of meanings](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/set)

Comment: It's true, because (as you've already seen) there are phonetic loan usages for characters. Also, this shouldn't be tagged `simplified-chinese` - Chinese, from the beginning of its written history, has used characters for multiple meanings. That's why many of them became more complex in the first place - to distinguish between different words from an overloaded base character.

Comment: so it's like homophone or homograph phenomena?

Comment: This happens with some super common characters, like 了 and 得

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

[处](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqtm=1&wdqcham=1&wdqt=%E5%A4%84) also has two different readings:

> chǔ

and

> chù

with many different meanings.

chǔ for instance means:

> to reside / to live / to dwell / to be in / to be situated at / to stay / to get along with / to be in a position of / to deal with / to discipline / to punish

while chù means:

> place / location / spot / point / office / department / bureau / respect / classifier for locations or items of damage: spot, point

This is not uncommon, especially with simplified characters as sometimes multiple traditional characters get simplified into the same singular character, you just need to know when what means what.

Answer (score 1):

> Can one chinese character represent many different words?

Most Chinese characters only *pertain* to something, akin to prefixes or suffixes in English, and ordinarily not used alone.  When someone asks *what does this character mean?* the answer typically varies with what word it's contained in.

For example [平](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%B3) (flat) would not ordinarily be used by itself (although occasionally it is);  it'd usually belong to a word such as [平衡](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%B3%E8%A1%A1) (balance), [和平](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%92%8C%E5%B9%B3) (peace), [平安](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%B3%E5%AE%89) (safety), [公平](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%85%AC%E5%B9%B3) (fair), [平凡](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%B3%E5%87%A1) (ordinary), etc.

With that in mind, single-character words are relatively few, but they can have multiple distinct meanings.  Here are some examples which arise in early Chinese studies:

- **米** (mǐ) means both "a meter" (一百**米** = 100 meters) and "rice" (两斤**米** = 1kg rice)
- **生** (shēng) means both "to give birth" (我**生**宝宝了 = I gave birth) and "raw" (那个肉是**生**的 = that meat is raw).
- **站** (zhàn) means both "to stand" (我**站**在这儿 = I stand here) and "station" (这是哪个**站**? = what station is this?)
- **等** (děng) means both "to wait" (我**等**你 = I wait for you) and "etc." (房子、汽车**等** = house, car, etc.)
- **角** (jiǎo) means both "corner" (三角形有三个**角** = triangles have three corners) and "0.1 yuan" (一元等于十**角** = one yuan equals 10 jiao)
- **读** (dú) means both "to study" (**读**科学 = study science) and "to read" (**读**书 = read a book)
- **贵** (guì) means both "expensive" (太**贵**了 = too expensive) and "precious" (很**贵**的宝宝 = precious baby)

Sometimes they also have different pronunciations:

- **还** means both "still" [pronounced hái] (你**还**爱我吗? = do you still love me?) and "to return" [pronounced huán] (我**还**了车 = I returned the car)
- **只** means "only" [pronounced zhǐ] (我**只**是一个人) and is a measure word for certain animals [pronounced zhī] (一**只**鸟 = a bird)

Some of the above examples have additional meanings.